# why this crash with No pending exception expected: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase

I was making an app that had firebase authentication. First, everything was going well but later this when I open the app it shuts down immediately. I have tried restarting android studio, but nothing happen. I only understand this is something about the layout but cant what is the real issue.

I don't know what is causing this error.

```
`A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1336] No pending exception expected: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Object) (DexFile.java:-2)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Object, java.util.List) (DexFile.java:226)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.util.List) (DexFile.java:219)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(java.lang.String, java.util.List) (DexPathList.java:338)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:511)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:469)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:628)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:809)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:749)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:880)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:843)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:521)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:429)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:380)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:896)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:170)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at void com.example.uchat.LoginActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (LoginActivity.java:43)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6308)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1114)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2445)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2552)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:166)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1399)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:148)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:5541)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:853)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:737)
    art/runtime/thread.cc:1336] 
A/art: art/runtime/barrier.cc:90] Check failed: count_ == 0 (count_=-1, 0=0) Attempted to destroy barrier with non zero count
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] Runtime aborting --- recursively, so no thread-specific detail!
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] 
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 31060 (m.example.uchat)`
```

This the layout:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="171dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_account_circle_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:hint="Enter your phone number"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.696"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.336" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/code"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:hint="Enter verification code"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.321"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.448" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="18dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_round"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:text="Send Verification code"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.581" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
```

This the main activity:

```
 package com.example.uchat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText phoneNumber, code;
    private Button sendBtn;

    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallBack;

    String verificationId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);


        userIsLoggedIn();

        phoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
        code = findViewById(R.id.code);
        sendBtn = findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);

        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(verificationId != null)
                    verifyPhoneNumberWithCode();

                else
                    startPhoneNumberVerification();
            }
        });

        mCallBack = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                SignInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);

                verificationId = s;
                sendBtn.setText("Verify Code");

            }
        };
    }

    private void verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(){
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code.getText().toString());
        SignInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    }

    private void SignInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                    if(user != null){
                        final DatabaseReference userdb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(user.getUid());
                        userdb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                if(!snapshot.exists()){
                                    Map<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                                    userMap.put("phone", user.getPhoneNumber());
                                    userMap .put("name", user.getPhoneNumber());
                                }
                                userIsLoggedIn();
                            }



                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                else{
                    System.out.println("unsuccesfull");
                }
            }

        });
    }

    private void userIsLoggedIn() {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if(user != null){
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainPageActivity.class));
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }
    public void startPhoneNumberVerification(){
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber.getText().toString(),
                60,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                this,
                mCallBack);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:textColor="#ffff"` Text color for your button is incorrect. Hex colors should only contain 3 or 6 symbols or 8 if you apply alpha.